# Eclipse, TomCat6 Spring 2.0.6

Tags: eclipse, spring, tomcat6

Hey everyone I am trying to get back into Spring programming on tomcat6.  Can someone please tell me which versions I should use and if the following will work

Eclispe EE
Tomcat 6
Springs 2.0.6

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know for sure about Eclipse (beyond the obvious “make sure you've got the latest version”, which is the Helios platform IIRC) but Tomcat6 is still in reasonable production as a development target where I work. The big change is that Spring's now up to version 3, which supports a much wider range of annotation-based configuration (most of which I don't use, to be fair; I don't mind having XML configurations).